# Apply scipy binned_statistic by dask

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, dask, scipy.stats

Is it possible to add `binned_statistic` to `dask.stats`? Or other solutions like embedding it in `apply.ufunc()`?

Here's an example using `scipy.stats`:

```
from scipy.stats import binned_statistic
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(500)
values = x*50

statistics, _, _ = binned_statistic(x, values, statistic='min', bins=500, range=(0, 500))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest way to get the minimum value of data array in another paired bin array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67882615/fastest-way-to-get-the-minimum-value-of-data-array-in-another-paired-bin-array)