# Fastest way to get the minimum value of data array in another paired bin array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, dask

I have three 1D arrays:

- `idxs`: the index data
- `weights`: the weight of each index in `idxs`
- `bins`: the bin which is used to calculate minimum weight in it.

Here's my current method of using the `idxs` to check the data called `weights` in which bin, and then calculate the min/max of binned weights:

[image: illustration]

1. Get `slices` that shows which bin each `idxs` element belongs to.
2. Sort `slices` and `weights` at the same time.
3. Calculate the minimum of `weights` in each bin (slice).

### numpy method

```
import random
import numpy as np

# create example data
out_size = int(10)
bins = np.arange(3, out_size-3)
idxs = np.arange(0, out_size)
#random.shuffle(idxs)

# set duplicated slice manually for test
idxs[4] = idxs[3]
idxs[6] = idxs[7]

weights = idxs

# get which bin idxs belong to
slices = np.digitize(idxs, bins)

# get index and weights in bins
valid = (bins.max() >= idxs) & (idxs >= bins.min())
valid_slices = slices[valid]
valid_weights = weights[valid]

# sort slice and weights
sort_index = valid_slices.argsort()
valid_slices_sort = valid_slices[sort_index]
valid_weights_sort = valid_weights[sort_index]

# get index of each first unque slices
unique_slices, unique_index = np.unique(valid_slices_sort, return_index=True)
# calculate the minimum
res_sub = np.minimum.reduceat(valid_weights_sort, unique_index)

# save results
res = np.full((out_size), np.nan)
res[unique_slices-1] = res_sub

print(res)
```

Results:

```
array([ 3., nan,  5., nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan])
```

If I increase the `out_size` to 1e7 and shuffle the data, the speed (from np.digitize to the end) is slow:

```
13.5 s ± 136 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

And, here's the consumed time of each part:

```
np.digitize: 10.8 s ± 12.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
valid: 171 ms ± 3.78 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
argsort and slice: 2.02 s ± 33.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
unique: 9.9 ms ± 113 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
np.minimum.reduceat: 5.11 ms ± 52.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

`np.digitize()` costs the most of time: 10.8 s. And, the next is `argsort`: 2.02 s.

I also check the consumed time of calculating `mean` using `np.histogram`:

```
counts, _ = np.histogram(idxs, bins=out_size, range=(0, out_size))
sums, _ = np.histogram(idxs, bins=out_size, range=(0, out_size), weights = weights, density=False)
mean = sums / np.where(counts == 0, np.nan, counts)

33.2 s ± 3.47 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

This is similar to my method of calculating minimum.

### scipy method

```
from scipy.stats import binned_statistic
statistics, _, _ = binned_statistic(idxs, weights, statistic='min', bins=bins)

print(statistics)
```

The result is a little different, but the speed is much slower (x6) for the longer(1e7) shuffled data:

```
array([ 3., nan,  5.])

1min 20s ± 6.93 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

### Summary

I want to figure out a quicker method. If the method is also suitable for [dask](https://dask.org/), that would be excellent!

### User Case

Here's how my real data (1D) look like:
[image: real data]

Comment: For your actual use case, do you need to maintain the weights functionality of binned_statistic? (e.g. for computing 'mean')

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev The weights are just the data. I don't need to multiply it for calculation. Sorry for the misleading name. I just want to get the minimum or maximum or mean of data within each bin.

Comment: OK, it's just min/max are easy to do without `binned_statistic`, but for calculating the mean, the weights matter... I'll think of a good answer.

Comment: For the mean, I know the quick method: just calculate the sum and count using histogram. Please feel free to post the min/max solution ;)

Comment: Any assumptions about your data being ordered/sorted? digitization or computing a histogram usualy involves sorting, so you will have a hard time beating O(nlog(n)), unless you can make assumptions on the ordering of your data.

Comment: Same question, but for the range and data types. Is it integers only like in the example or floats, too? is there an upper and/or lower bound?

Comment: @FirefoxMetzger The `idx` is `int64` with ascending order with many fill_value. The `weights` is `float64` and no order. See the added `User Case` Section.

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev Hope you don't misunderstand the situation. I use the `idxs` to check the data called `weights` in which bin, and then calculate the min/max of binned `weights`. If you know the faster method, could you teach me how to apply it using `dask`? Thanks!

Comment: This looks like `bins = np.range(0, max_bin)`. Is that intuition coming from your plots correct?

Comment: @FirefoxMetzger Yes, that's similar to `range=(0, out_size)` used in the `np.histogram()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SultanOrazbayev showed a quick approach; I'll add a cool one.

```py
mask = bins[:, None] == idxs[None, :]
result = np.nanmin(np.where(mask, weights, np.nan), axis=-1)
# Note: may produce (expected) runtime warning if bin has no values
```

of course, you can also do `np.nanmax`, `np.nanmean`, etc.

The above assumes that your bins are indeed single values. If they are ranges, you need slightly little more work to construct the mask

```py
lower_mask = idxs[None, :] >= bins[:, None]
upper_mask = np.empty_like(lower_mask)
upper_mask[:-1, ...] = idxs[None, :] < bins[1:, None]
upper_mask[-1, ...] = False

mask = lower_mask & upper_mask
```

at which point you can use `np.nanmin` like above.

---

Ofc `np.where` and the broadcast to create a mask will create new arrays of shape (len(bins), len(idxs)) with their respective datatype. If this is of no concern to you, then the above is probably good enough.

If it is a problem (because you are pressed for RAM), then my first suggestion is to buy more RAM. If - for some stupid reason (say, money) - that doesn't work, you can avoid the copy of `weights` by using a masked array over a manually re-strided view into `weights`

```py
import numpy.ma as ma

mask = ...

restrided_weights = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(weights, shape=(bins.size, idxs.size), strides=(0, idxs.strides[0]))
masked = ma.masked_array(restrided_weights, mask=~mask, fill_value=np.nan, dtype=np.float64)
result = masked.min(axis=-1).filled(np.nan)
```

this avoids both, a copy of `weights` and the above-mentioned runtime warning.

If you don't even have enough memory to construct `mask`, then you can try processing the data in chunks.

Last I checked, Dask used to have funny behavior when fed with manually strided arrays. There was some work on this though, so you may want to double-check if that is resolved, in which case you can happily parallelize the above.

---

**Update** based on your further comments to this answer and the other:

You can do this computation in chunks to avoid memory issues due to your large number of bins (1e4 in magnitude). Putting the concrete numbers into a full example and adding a progress bar indicates <40 seconds runtime on a single core.

```py
import numpy.ma as ma
from tqdm import trange
import numpy as np
import random

# create example data
out_size = int(1.5e5)
#bins = np.arange(3, out_size-3)
bins = np.arange(3, int(3.8e4-3), dtype=np.int64)
idxs = np.arange(0, out_size)
random.shuffle(idxs)

# set duplicated slice manually for test
idxs[4] = idxs[3]
idxs[6] = idxs[7]

weights = idxs

chunk_size = 100

# preallocate buffers to avoid array creation in main loop
extended_bins = np.empty(len(bins) + 1, dtype=bins.dtype)
extended_bins[:-1] = bins
extended_bins[-1] = np.iinfo(bins.dtype).max # last bin goes to infinity
mask_buffer = np.empty((chunk_size, len(idxs)), dtype=bool)


result = np.empty_like(bins, dtype=np.float64)

for low in trange(0, len(bins), chunk_size):
    high = min(low + chunk_size, len(bins))
    chunk_size = high - low
    mask_buffer[:chunk_size, ...] = ~((bins[low:high, None] <= idxs[None, :]) & (extended_bins[low+1:high+1, None] > idxs[None, :]))
    mask = mask_buffer[:chunk_size, ...]
    restrided_weights = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(weights, shape=mask.shape, strides=(0, idxs.strides[0]))
    masked = ma.masked_array(restrided_weights, mask=mask, fill_value=np.nan, dtype=np.float64)
    result[low:high] = masked.min(axis=-1).filled(np.nan)
```

**Bonus**: For `min` and `max` *only* there is a cool trick that you can use: sort `idxs` and `weights` based on `weights` (ascending for min, descending for max). This way, you can immediately look up the min/max value and can avoid the masked array and the custom strides altogether. This relies on some not so well documented behavior of `np.argmax`, which takes a fast-pass for boolean arrays and doesn't search the full array.

It only works for these two cases, and you'd have to fall back to the above for more sophisticated things (mean), but for those two it shaves off another ~70% and a run on a single core clocks in at <12 seconds.

```py
# fast min/max
from tqdm import trange
import numpy as np

# create example data
out_size = int(1.5e5)
#bins = np.arange(3, out_size-3)
bins = np.arange(3, int(3.8e4-3), dtype=np.int64)
idxs = np.arange(0, out_size)
random.shuffle(idxs)

# set duplicated slice manually for test
idxs[4] = idxs[3]
idxs[6] = idxs[7]

weights = idxs


order = np.argsort(weights)
weights_sorted = np.empty((len(weights) + 1), dtype=np.float64)
weights_sorted[:-1] = weights[order]
weights_sorted[-1] = np.nan

idxs_sorted = idxs[order]

extended_bins = np.empty(len(bins) + 1, dtype=bins.dtype)
extended_bins[:-1] = bins
extended_bins[-1] = np.iinfo(bins.dtype).max # last bin goes to infinity

# preallocate buffers to avoid array creation in main loop
chunk_size = 1000
mask_buffer = np.empty((chunk_size, len(idxs) + 1), dtype=bool)
mask_buffer[:, -1] = True
result = np.empty_like(bins, dtype=np.float64)

for low in trange(0, len(bins), chunk_size):
    high = min(low + chunk_size, len(bins))
    chunk_size = high - low
    mask_buffer[:chunk_size, :-1] = (bins[low:high, None] <= idxs_sorted[None, :]) & (extended_bins[low+1:high+1, None] > idxs_sorted[None, :])
    mask = mask_buffer[:chunk_size, ...]
    weight_idx = np.argmax(mask, axis=-1)

    result[low:high] = weights_sorted[weight_idx]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting, makes me want to try this with dask.arrays at some point.

Comment: @FirefoxMetzger Your method is incredible! I tested it with my example and found a strange problem: As you said, I get this memory error when increasing the length to 1e5. But, increasing it to 1e7, the first method returns one value: `nan`, while the second one still gets the memory error.

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev If I applied this method with dask like this: `bins = da.array(bins)` and `idxs = da.array(idxs)`, I get the similar error like the above. I suppose simply converting into dask array has no improvement at all. Do you have any idea what's the correct way to meet it?

Comment: @XinZhang applying with dask array will be a bit more involved than wrapping everything in `da.array`...

Comment: @XinZhang I've updated the answer in response to your concern about memory usage. You can, of course, refactor the above approach to use a dask array and multi-threading if you wish; personally, I think < 1 min runtime is acceptable as it is an easy justification for a quick coffee break. Regarding your finding of `np.where` producing a single `nan` as a result I am not sure why this happens, but can reproduce it on my machine.

Comment: Thanks! That's quite faster without memory error ;) But, sorry, it still sounds difficult for me to apply the dask method ... @SultanOrazbayev, do you have any dask ideas? Appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 3):

A quick approach to achieve this is with `dask.dataframe` and `pd.cut`, I first show the `pandas` version:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import binned_statistic as bs
import pandas as pd

nrows=10**7

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(nrows, 2), columns=['x', 'val'])

bins = np.linspace(df['x'].min(), df['x'].max(), 10)

df['binned_x'] = pd.cut(df['x'], bins=bins, right=False)

result_pandas = df.groupby('binned_x')['val'].min().values
result_scipy = bs(df['x'], df['val'], 'min', bins=bins)[0]

print(np.isclose(result_pandas, result_scipy))
# [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
```

Now to go from `pandas` to `dask`, you will need to make sure that bins are consistent across partitions, so take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67791235/10693596). Once every partition is binned consistently, you want to apply the desired operation (min/max/sum/count):

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=10)

def f(df, bins):
    df = df.copy()
    df['binned_x'] = pd.cut(df['x'], bins=bins, right=False)
    result = df.groupby('binned_x', as_index=False)['val'].min()
    return result

result_dask = ddf.map_partitions(f, bins).groupby('binned_x')['val'].min().compute()

print(np.isclose(result_pandas, result_dask))
# [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
```

On my laptop, the first code take about <s>7</s> 3 seconds, the second code is about <s>10</s> times faster (forgot that I am double-counting both pandas and scipy performing the same operation). There is scope for playing around with partitioning, but that's context-dependent, so something you can try optimizing on your data/hardware.

Update: note that this approach will work for min/max, but for mean you will want to calculate sum and count and then divide them. There is probably a good way of keeping track of weights in doing this calculation in one go, but it might not be worth the added code complexity.

Comment: Thanks, this method works well without memory errorr. Could FirefoxMetzger's method be combined with dask? That may increase the speed and save memory at the same time.

Comment: Yes, I am certain it is possible.

Comment: @XinZhang While re-reading Sultan's answer I realized that he/she has fixed the number of 10 `bins` and scaled `idxs` and `weights` to `1e7`. Are we looking for a solution that keeps the number of bins low, or is the number of bins `1e7` (or somewhere in that magnitude)?

Comment: @FirefoxMetzger The exact length of each data is shown as the x-axis called dim_0 in the `User Case` at the end of question description. The number of idxs and weights is around 1.5e5, the number of bins is around 3.8e4.